# Exporting a binary based file with Python

Tags: java, python, binary, utf-16, utf-32

I'm am currently working on a export script for Blender, however I feel my question is more based around Python in general so I've posted it here.

A friend created a conversion program in java for .obj files , which turns them into a custom binary file format. However, I want to skip that process and export the binary file directly from Blender.

The file contains text, integers and floats, using utf-8, utf-16 and utf-32 formats.

So far I have all the data exporting as a standard text file, so I just need to output it in the appropriate encoding/format. Here is the code he is using in Java for writing the data to the file in different encodings:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class StreamConverter {

//---------------------------------------------------

public static void buffer_write_string(DataOutputStream out,String text) throws IOException{
    byte[] bytes = text.getBytes();
    for(int i =0;i<text.length();i++){
        buffer_write_u8(out,bytes[i]);
    }
}

public static void buffer_write_u32(DataOutputStream out,int i) throws IOException{
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); 
    b.putInt(i);
    out.write(b.array());       
}

public static void buffer_write_u16(DataOutputStream out,int i) throws IOException{
    out.write((byte) i);
    out.write((byte) (i >> 8));     
}

public static void buffer_write_s16(DataOutputStream out,int i) throws IOException{
    out.write((byte) i);
    out.write((byte) (i >> 8));     
}

public static void buffer_write_s32(DataOutputStream out,int i) throws IOException{
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); 
    b.putInt(i);
    out.write(b.array());
}

public static void buffer_write_u8(DataOutputStream out,int i) throws IOException{
    out.writeByte((byte) i);
}

public static void buffer_write_s8(DataOutputStream out,int i) throws IOException{
    out.writeByte((byte) i);
}

public static void buffer_write_f64(DataOutputStream out,double i) throws IOException{
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); 
    b.putDouble(i);
    out.write(b.array());

}

public static void buffer_write_f32(DataOutputStream out,float i) throws IOException{
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); 
    b.putFloat(i);
    out.write(b.array());
}

}
```

I'm not sure how to do this is Python, I'm trying this to see if I can at least get integers to output correctly but no luck.

```
def write_u8(file, num):
    enum = num.encode('utf-8')
    file.write(enum)

def write_u16(file, num):
    enum = num.encode('utf-16')
    file.write(enum)

def write_u32(file, num):
    enum = num.encode('utf-32')
    file.write(enum)
```

example usage:

```
write_u32(file, u'%i' % (vertex_count))
```

also tried this:

```
counts = bytes([vertex_count,tex_count,normal_count])
file.write(counts)
```

I'm a bit lost with this whole binary/encoding thing, I've read through the Python documentation, but it hasn't helped.

Any links to tutorials or examples would be great!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you would like to do is serialize your object and deserialize it back. In Python, `Pickle` is the package you are looking for. You can look at its documentation right [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).